# VS2019 update gives FragmentManager error

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-fragmentactivity

I recently upgraded my installation of VisualStudio 2019 from 16.4.19 to 16.9.3
After cleaning up a few errors, it builds just fine.
When I try to deploy and run it on a 7.0 tablet, I get the message:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException Message=FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.
```

Here is the code that generates the problem:

```
void Navigate(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment)
{
    var transaction = base.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.contentFrame, fragment);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

And this code calls it:

```
void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, Android.Support.Design.Widget.NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Vars.OnMain = false;    //turn off screen updates until mainscreen is open
    switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.aboutMenuItem: Navigate(new AboutFragment()); break;
        case Resource.Id.catalogMenuItem: Navigate(new CatalogFragment()); break;
        //case Resource.Id.itemMenuItem: Navigate(new ItemFragment()); break;
        case Resource.Id.helpMenuItem: Navigate(new HelpFragment()); break;
        case Resource.Id.settingsMenuItem: Navigate(new SettingsFragment()); break;
        case Resource.Id.coordinateMenuItem: Navigate(new CoordinateFragment()); break;
        case Resource.Id.mainMenuItem: Navigate(new MainScreenFragment()); break;
        default: return;
    }

    e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);

    //var drawerLayout = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawerLayout);
    drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.End);
}
```

The App has been running for years and is too large to post here.

Has something changed in the VS2019 environment during the last year that would cause this problem?

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

From the following code you posted,we found that you're getting the fragment manager from the `base` variable. Where does base itself get the `FragmentManager`? When you `Navigate`, the activity maybe been destroyed and recreated. Therefore, you might need to get a new FragmentManager.

```
void Navigate(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment)
{
    var transaction = base.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.contentFrame, fragment);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

So, you can try to use the following code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.contentFrame, fragment);
transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I get the same error. This code was generated by Xamarin many years ago. What is the proper way to handle fragments with the new system?

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can try ourself?

Comment: While the program itself is too large to post, it was derived from the first part of the Xamarin AND205 course. (Navigation Patterns) Naturally, the materials from the course no longer build using the current VS2019. I am in the process of tweeking the course material to make it compile.

Comment: Any updates? Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: No, I haven't solved the problem, but I have to get on with the project, so I loaded 16.4.23 so that it will build and run. I will have to chase this problem down later. Thanks anyway.